# Evaluate several expression, continue to next id when true

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have 2 SQL tables like following:

**1.Noise**

| Noise_Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 73 |
| 7 | 57 |
| 8 | 78 |
| 12 | 86 |
| 14 | 89 |

**2. Color**

```
|ColorInt |Criteria       |SortOrder|
|---------|---------------|---------|
|-1       | [Value] < 75  | 75      |
|-16711936| [Value] < 80  | 80      |
|-128     | [Value] < 85  | 85      |
|-10496   | [Value] < 90  | 90      |
|-23296   | [Value] < 95  | 95      |
|-65536   | [Value] < 100 | 100     |
|-38476   | [Value] < 105 | 105     |
|-8388480 | [Value] < 110 | 110     |
|-11861886| [Value] >= 110| 111     |
```

This [Criteria] column can contain other expressions such as:

```
[Value]=1
[Value]=2
[Value]=3
[Value]=4
[Value]=5
FindingsCnt_Overdue > 0
FindingsCnt_Completed = FindingsCnt - FindingsCnt_Deleted
[Value] = -1
[Value] < 30
[Value] < 50
[Value] < 70
[Value] < 90
[Value] < 110
[Value] < 150
[Value] >= 150
```

I want to calculate the [ColorInt] from the [Criteria] for each [Noise_Id] as in:

**Expected result**

| Noise_Id | Value | ColorInt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 73 | -1 |
| 7 | 57 | -1 |
| 8 | 78 | -16711936 |
| 12 | 86 | -10496 |
| 14 | 89 | -10496 |

How could I create an efficient stored procedure or function that will evaluate expression in the [Criteria] column for each [Noise_Id] and go to the next [Noise_Id] when a [Criteria] is met?

This is the code that I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results (
Noise_Id int,
Value varchar(MAX)) 

DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX)=''

SELECT @SQL = 
@SQL+' Insert Into #Results(Noise_Id, Value) Select '+cast(Noise_Id AS varchar(50))+', case when '+Replace([Criteria],'[Value]',Value)+' then [ColorInt] else null end as Value FROM [Noise] where Noise_Id = '+cast(Noise_Id AS varchar(50))
FROM [Noise] 

exec (@sql)

select * from #Results

drop table #Results
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What is/are the criteria?  What is the expected output?

Comment: Hi! I just edited the question because StackOverflow doesn't allow a table with operator, so I need to format it as a code. thanks!

Comment: Also, the table color comes from the system where I don't have admin power, so unfortunately I have to work with the [Criteria] column as it is.

Comment: Does your column `Criteria` really have the value `N'[Value] < 75'`? If so the only method is with dynamic SQL and I strongly recommend against that. If you do go down that route (don't) I hope you have **very good** processes to ensure that the expressions in the column can't perform any form of injection. If you don't, then don't go anywhere near a dynamic solution; fix the design instead (which is the real solution anyway).

Comment: @Larnu it does have that value and can contain other expressions which I will add in the problem, so unfortunately breaking it by operator wouldn't be 100% fit answer.

Comment: If you have other operations as well you should have included that in the question too, however, that just makes my point stronger; it's the design that needs changing here. Unless you *really* know what you're doing with dynamic SQL and you have the safety measures on the data going into the column, then using dynamic SQL is only going to be a (huge) security flaw.

Comment: To Tim, Dale, and @Larnu thanks for the feedback, the question is updated. I wouldn't claim to really know about dynamic SQL, but the purpose of this is to get color only and not inserting or updating any value.

Comment: @Larnu The case of the wandering goal posts. I think these ones have wandered off the pitch. I give up.

Comment: Ye, I stand by my statements then @savvyt . There is only 1 solution: change the design. This will only be a nightmare to work with and likely a huge security hole. Imagine, for example, if someone entered the criteria `N'1=1; CREATE LOGIN S WITH PASSWORD ='1', CHECK_POLICY = OFF; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER S; --`. Do *you* have a parser in your application to stop such statements?

Comment: What is the order in which to process `Noise_Id` values? We need to know that in order to stop when no criterion is met: "go to the next [Noise_Id] when a [Criteria] is met".

Comment: Thanks @Larnu for the feedback! I now see the threat and will try Charlieface's logic instead of running the raw expression.

Comment: @HABO I have marked an answer as a solution, but thanks for the question! Order is the [SortOrder] column in the Color table

Comment: Doesn't `SortOrder` in `Color` identify the order in which to apply `Criteria`? Your question states: "go to the **next** [Noise_Id] **when** a [Criteria] is met" _(emphasis added)_. How is the "next" `Noise_Id` determined by `SortOrder` in `Color`? If none of the criteria are met for a `Noise_Id` then you don't want to proceed to the "next" `Noise_Id`, right? The accepted answer doesn't apply any order to `Noise_Id` values, nor does it stop processing `Noise` rows when all criteria fail for a `Noise` row. Perplexing.

Comment: @HABO You're quite right, it's unclear. But I read that as "find the first matching Criteria for a Noise, then go to the next Noise, RBAR-style"

Comment: @HABO for example `Noise_Id` = 2 has 73 as `Value`, it will evaluate against the `Criteria` from highest `SortOrder` until it hits True and return `ColorInt` else (maybe) return null and go to next `Noise_Id`. What I understand from the solution I accepted is that it evaluates against all the criteria and then select top 1 after ordered by `SortOrder` which returns the result that I need, though not using the break - continue thing. Not sure which one would perform better when we have more criteria and data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to split up the `Criteria` into separate columns: `Op` defining what the comparison should be, and `Criteria` defining what value to compare to.**

You can then compare to each possible operator separately.

After that it's just a simple `TOP 1` per group query.

```sql
SELECT
    n.Noise_Id
    n.[Value],
    c.ColorInt
FROM Noise n
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 c.ColorInt
    FROM Color c
    WHERE
        (c.Op = '<'  AND n.[Value] <  c.Criteria) OR
        (c.Op = '<=' AND n.[Value] <= c.Criteria) OR
        (c.Op = '='  AND n.[Value] =  c.Criteria) OR
        (c.Op = '>'  AND n.[Value] >  c.Criteria) OR
        (c.Op = '>=' AND n.[Value] >= c.Criteria)
    ORDER BY c.SortOrder
) c
```

---

You say you cannot modify the `Criteria` column. Then we have to split it ourselves.

I assume `Value` is always at the beginning, the comparator in the middle, and there are spaces. This will fail otherwise.

```sql
SELECT
    n.Noise_Id
    n.[Value],
    c.ColorInt
FROM Noise n
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 c.ColorInt
    FROM Color c
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
        CAST(RIGHT(c.Criteria, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(c.Criteria)) - 1) AS int)  -- same data type as n.Value
    ) ) v(CriteriaNum)
    WHERE
        (c.Criteria LIKE '%<%'  AND n.[Value] <  v.CriteriaNum) OR
        (c.Criteria LIKE '%<=%' AND n.[Value] <= v.CriteriaNum) OR
        (c.Criteria LIKE '%=%'  AND n.[Value] =  v.CriteriaNuma) OR
        (c.Criteria LIKE '%>%'  AND n.[Value] >  v.CriteriaNum) OR
        (c.Criteria LIKE '%>=%' AND n.[Value] >= v.CriteriaNum)
    ORDER BY c.SortOrder
) c
```

Comment: Cue the OP saying that the name of the column (in this case `Value`) can be dynamic and that operators like `BETWEEN` can be in there too. 

Comment: @Charlieface and Larnu thanks for the feedback! I just updated the question and posted the code that I've tried.

Comment: awesome! thanks @Charlieface for the help! I had a hiccup with the code so need to adjust CAST(RIGHT(c.Criteria, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(c.Criteria)) - 1) AS int) to CAST(RIGHT(c.Criteria,LEN(c.criteria)-cast(patINDEX('%[0-9]%', c.Criteria) as int)+1) AS int)